# How to know total number of downloads for an ios app.?

Tags: ios5, download, app-store, itunes-store

How to know total number of downloads for an ios app. ?
In sales and trends under my developers account it shows only weekly or daily. Where can i see total number of downloads ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

ItunesConnect doesn't really have an easy way to do this.

In the sales and trend section you can only access 15 days worth of data with a daily breakdown or 3 month with a weekly breakdown and no total number is displayed

In the Financial report section, all your historical data is accessible but you won't find a total as well.

Best thing to do is either:
-to manually export daily (or weekly) your sales report and group all your figures in a spreadsheet
-to use a service like App Annie (http://www.appannie.com) which does that automatically for you.

Comment: Very bad of Apple that there is no easy way of retrieving important stats like the total download count etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think Eric Genet was correct butApple just updated https://itunesconnect.apple.com site you can adjust the date range in the middle of screen (using the slider) or by adjusting the dates on top left corner after navigating to sale and trends screen to see how many downloads you have had.

[image]

Comment: How much is average downloads for a normal app on app store ?

Comment: @SamkitJain I don't have aggregated data for all apps on app store to share with you beside maybe googleing something but if you want to get average of your app you can simply divide the total number of download but total number of days since you released the app.  (Also if you find the above answer useful/accurate please give it  a vote up. Thanks

Comment: if you have released an app ..how much downloads you are getting on daily basis ..just want to knoe that

Comment: @SamkitJain thanks for the vote up, in the early days I was getting 80 downloads now I am getting 35 downloads after two months. It dependents on your app and how much marketing you do for it.

Comment: @SamkitJain correct per day. Mine is a free app so I don't have any number for a paid app to share with you.

Comment: @SamkitJain welcome and happy you have such a great download :)

Comment: You can also download my app @ https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tic-tac-toe-.../id825924666?ls=1&mt=8